# webservice method parameter always null

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, null, asmx

I created a C # webservice through a WSDL from another webservice made in PHP. All calls work but the parameters sent in xml always arrive null.
This is my code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "urn:PGSMS")]
[GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3082")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapType(Namespace = "urn:PGSMS")]
[SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class PGSMS : System.Web.Services.WebService, PGSMSPortType
{
    [WebMethod]
    [OperationContract(Action = "urn:PGSMS#PGSMS")]
    public string envioAvulso(string token, string carteira, string msg, string fones, string data, string retorno, string dadocliente)
    {
        IntegraBellinati.envioAvulsoRequest envio = new IntegraBellinati.envioAvulsoRequest();
        envio.token = token;
        envio.msg = msg;
        envio.fones = fones;
        envio.carteira = carteira;
        envio.data = data;
        envio.dadocliente = dadocliente;
        envio.retorno = retorno;

        IntegraBellinati.IntegraBellinati integra = new IntegraBellinati.IntegraBellinati();
        return integra.envioAvulso(envio);
    }

}
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:PGSMS", ConfigurationName = "PGSMSPortType")]
public interface PGSMSPortType
{    
    string envioAvulso(string token, string carteira, string msg, string fones, string data, string retorno, string dadocliente);
}
```

The method sendsAvulso executes normally, but all methods arrive null.
This is the xml that my client is trying to post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:PGSMS" xmlns:types="urn:PGSMS/encodedTypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<tns:envioAvulso>
<token xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</token>
<carteira xsi:type="xsd:string">12</carteira>
<msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Teste de msg</msg>
<fones xsi:type="xsd:string">41988326802</fones>
<data xsi:type="xsd:string">2017-10-09 00:00:00</data>
<retorno xsi:type="xsd:string">12</retorno>
<dadocliente xsi:type="xsd:string">12</dadocliente>
</tns:envioAvulso>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using SoapUI I was able to make the post and received the correct parameters, it generated this xml.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:PGSMS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:envioAvulso>
         <urn:token>?</urn:token>
         <urn:carteira>?</urn:carteira>
         <urn:msg>?</urn:msg>
         <urn:fones>?</urn:fones>
         <urn:data>?</urn:data>
         <urn:retorno>?</urn:retorno>
         <urn:dadocliente>?</urn:dadocliente>
      </urn:envioAvulso>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But my client can not change his xml. What can I be doing wrong?
Thank's

Comment: The namespace do not match.  Your code has urn while customer has tns and in most cases no namespace.  Your definition has : Namespace = "urn:PGSMS"